# How to repeat gherkin snippet in Karate?

Tags: javascript, loops, karate, repeat, gherkin

I have a snippet of Gherkin that builds a JSON body and makes an API call.

I can reuse this snippet in other Karate features via:

```
* call read("/path/to/snippet.feature")
```

I have a scenario where I need to repeat this API call, so I want to run this snippet N times.

`karate.repeat()` exists; however, despite the name, it does not work with Karate gherkin files, or even `def`'ed Karate functions based on a feature file. Apparently, it only works with JS functions.

How do I repeat a call read() of another feature file an arbitrary number of times without having to explicitly repeat the line that many times? This could get unwieldy in a scenario where the number of calls needed for the scenario is more than a small few.

It seems the only solution is to *re*-implement that feature as a JS function, so that now I have both a Gherkin and a JS definition of the exact same functionality, which is a pattern that is begging for maintenance nightmares.

How can I call a Karate feature file multiple times in another Karate feature?

Comment: In reference, trying to use karate.repeat() with a token defined based ona  karate.read() of a feature file returns:

    org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (call) on com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge@a4b5ce3 failed due to: no applicable overload found (overloads: [Method[public java.lang.Object ...

Comment: someone asked almost the exact same thing a few hours back, please see linked / duplicate

Comment: how about that. well that did it, thank you.